# How to cache methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby, caching, rubygems

I have a ruby workflow which makes few expensive API calls. I know we have a easier way to cache things in Ruby on Rails but haven't found any common ruby gem for ruby scripts.

What is the simplest and easiest way to cache results for a method which depends on input for a pure ruby application?

```
//pseudo code
def get_information (id)
  user_details = expensive_api_call(id)
  return user_details
end
```

Comment: You don't want to cache the method but the result of the method call.

Comment: _Sidenote_: please never put a space between function name and parentheses. This may cause (in different cases) many unexpected problems.

Comment: What you're talking about is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). You can cache the output of a method based on its incoming parameters, if the called code always returns the same value for the same input. There are downsides to caching results for long-running processes though; If a value is used for a very short time, even if it's used 100 times, then never used again but remains cached for days/weeks/months, then it's wasting resources, so timing them out and purging them is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a Hash:

```
class ApiWithCache

  def initialize
    @cache = {}
  end

  def do_thing(id)
    expensive_api_call(id)
  end

  def do_thing_with_cache(id)
    @cache[id] ||= do_thing(id)
  end
end
```

Now this poses some problems that you might want to look into:

- expiry of cached data
- size of cache (will grow unless you also remove items. this could cause problems in long running processes)

Answer (score 2):

It is already pretty easy in pure ruby:

```
def foo(id)
  @foo[id] ||= some_expensive_operation
end
```

As far as gems go - check out [memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: This wont work. There is a parameter, so potentially different results.

Comment: @pascalbetz updated. Now it will work, given `foo` is a hash.

Comment: I just proposed an edit to add `[id]` to the question code that should clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an instance variable containing a hash, and the `||=` operator, as in:

```
def initialize
  @user_cache = {}
  # ...
end

def get_information(id)
  @user_cache[id] ||= expensive_api_call(id)
end
```

`||=` means execute the method call and perform the assignment only if the lvalue (in this case `@user_cache[id]`) is falsy (nil or false).  Otherwise, the value that is already in the hash is used.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by hash global variable

```
def get_information(id)
    @user_details ||= {}
    @user_details[id] ||= expensive_api_call(id)
    return @user_details[id]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [zache](https://github.com/yegor256/zache):

```
require 'zache'
zache = Zache.new
x = zache.get(:x, lifetime: 15) do
  # Something very slow and expensive, which
  # we only want to execute once every 15 seconds.
end
```

I'm the author.